# Some congruences and conclusion.

Tags: congruences

Let consider this situation:

$$ \gcd (b, m) = 1 \tag{$*$} \\
b^a \equiv 1 \\
b^c \equiv 1 $$
Assume that $ a \le c $
Whether it is reasonable to draw a conclusion that is $c = ak$ for some $k$? Why?  Is the $(*)$ condition is necessary? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First of all the (*) condition is necessary, because if $gcd(b,m)>1$ it means $b$ cannot have modulo inverse with respect to $m$. Thus $b^a \equiv 1$ would not be true for any $a$ as the inverse of $b$ would be $b^{(a-1)}$ which is not possible if $gcd(g,m) \neq 1$.
2. Secondly let $a$ be the smallest integer such that $b^a \equiv 1$, only then it is always  true that,
   if $b^c \equiv 1$ then $c=ak$.

**EDIT**

The proof for second point is simple assume $a$ is the smallest integer such that $b^a \equiv 1$ , also we have another integer $c$ such that $b^c \equiv 1$. Let us assume $c=ak+r$ where $r$ is remainder of division of $c$ by $a$. Thus $r<a$. Now we have
$$b^c \equiv 1$$
$$b^{(ak+r)} \equiv 1$$
as $b^a \equiv 1$ for some integer $k$, $b^{ak} \equiv 1 $ thus
$$b^r \equiv 1$$
This is a contradiction as $r<a$ and we assumed $a$ was the smallest integer such that $b^a \equiv 1$. Thus by contradiction $r=0$ and $c=ak$.

Comment: For 2. give me a proof, please.

Comment: @user180834 Hi added the proof in EDIT hope it is useful :)

Comment: thanks :). 
Now, Let assume that $a$ isn't the smallest integer such that $b^a \equiv 1$. We assume only $a<c$

Comment: it can be proved similarly,for example g=4 and m=5 take a=4 and c=6 , but c is not equal to 4*k